# Firemonkey TNotificationCenter did not work C++Builder 10.4

Tags: android, firemonkey, c++builder, rad-studio, c++builder-10.4-sydney

I am new to Firemonkey. I am using C++Builder 10.4 Sydney.  The target platform is Android.

My code is:

```cpp
...
unsigned short y, m, d, h, n, s, ms;
StrToDate(date).DecodeDate(&y, &m, &d); // might be: 2020, 7, 9
StrToTime(time).DecodeTime(&h, &n, &s, &ms); // might be: 13, 01, 00, 000

TNotification *myNotification=NotificationCenter1->CreateNotification();
try{
    myNotification->Number=1;
    myNotification->AlertBody="something";
    myNotification->EnableSound = true;
    myNotification->Title = "alert";
    myNotification->AlertAction = "GO";
    myNotification->SoundName = my_soundname;
    myNotification->FireDate = System::Dateutils::EncodeDateTime(y, m, d, h, n, s, ms);
                 
    myNotification->RepeatInterval=TRepeatInterval::Minute;
    NotificationCenter1->ScheduleNotification(myNotification);

} __finally { 
    myNotification->DisposeOf();
}
```

When time is up, nothing happens.

I tried adding Android Service to my project, but no dialog pops up (did 10.4 fixed dialog or is this a bug?).

And I added the Android Service manually with linker `libandroidService.a` and `System.Android.service.hpp`, and put this code in the Form's `OnCreate` event:

```cpp
TLocalServiceConnection::StartService("MyProject");
```

But still, nothing happens.

I tried `PresentNotification()`, just notified right now.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Are you really using Seattle (10.0), or are you actually using Sydney (10.4)?

Comment: I found bugs [RSP-22312](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-22312) and [RSP-22527](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-22527) that were fixed in 10.3 Rio. Use [`TNotification.ChannelId`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Notification.TNotification.ChannelId) with [`TCustomNotificationCenter.CreateChannel()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Notification.TCustomNotificationCenter.CreateChannel) (or `CreateAndUpdateChannel()`), as Android 8+ ignores notifications that don't have a channel assigned to them. Those features are not in Seattle.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau sorry ..my bad . its sydny 10.4

Comment: In that case, did you try using the [`TNotification.ChannelId`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Notification.TNotification.ChannelId) field with [`TNotificationCenter.CreateChannel()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Notification.TCustomNotificationCenter.CreateChannel) (or `CreateOrUpdateChannel()`) yet, like I suggested earlier?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I tried the code below:

`TChannel* pchannel =  NotificationCenter1->CreateChannel("Mychannel", "something");`
`pchannel->Importance = TImportance::Default;`
`...`
`myNotification->ChannelId = "Mychannel";`
`.....`
still nothing happens... was my code wrong ? 
Android 32 bit  25.2.5, platform android 9.0. two android machines tested, nothing happens

Comment: I tried add some more code:
`TChannel* pchannel =  NotificationCenter1->CreateChannel("Mychannel", "Something");`
`pchannel->Importance = TImportance::Default;`
`pchannel->ShouldShowLights = true;`
`pchannel->LockscreenVisibility = TLockscreenVisibility::Public;`
`pchannel->ShouldShowBadge = true;`
`NotificationCenter1->CreateOrUpdateChannel(pchanne);`
`......`
`myNotification->ChannelId = "Mychannel";`
still nothing happens